# Angular Router - how to find route to parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

Imagine routes set in this way:

```
module1Routes=  [
       {path: 'parent1': component: ParentComponent : children:[
           {path: 'child': component: ChildComponent},
           {path: 'result': component: ResultComponent}
       ]}
]

module2Routes=  [
       {path: 'parent2': component: Parent2Component : children:[
           {path: 'child': component: ChildComponent},
           {path: 'result': component: ResultComponent}
       ]}
]
```

Now the situation is like this. I have 2 modules, and on the end of processing `ChildComponent` I want to go to `ResultComponent`.

The issuse is how to know what is the correct path to`ResultComponent`?

If user is in path `parent1/child` I want next step to be `parent1/result`, but when user is on `parent2/child` next step should be `parent2/result`.

In my `ChildComponent` I have method `goToResult()` which responsibility is to navigate to `***/result`.
I'm confused how to know what is in `***`?

So the question is how know (in ChildComponent) what is the real route for a parent for this child?

I'm totaly stucked. I tried to build path to parent without child fragment but this doesen't work.
Any ideas?

I know I can use the `relativeTo` keyword in config of `router.navigate()`. The problem is I want to invoke `router.navigate()` in some service, so that I need to pass them a path to navigate

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Router to your Component and remove the child string from the current url.

**Variant A) Router + String manipulation (component.ts)**

```
constructor(private router: Router, private yourService: YourService) {

}

goToResult() {
   const path = this.router.url.replace('/child', '');
   this.yourService.goTo(path);
}
```

You might adjust the replace function, if the child can have multiple occurrences or you need to remove query parameters.

**Variant B) ActivatedRoute (component.ts)**

```
private parentUrl: string;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private yourService: YourService) {
    this.activatedRoute.parent.url.subscribe(path => {
        this.parentUrl = `/${path.join('/')}`;
    });
}

goToResult() {
   this.yourService.goTo(this.parentUrl);
}
```

Comment: this could be nice if I can make this without any string operations. String operations on routes are the violation of OpenClose principle in my opinion

Comment: I edited my answer and posted another variant via ActivatedRoute. What do you think about this approach?